# How to use filters in the LazyDataModel in PrimeFaces 10?

Tags: primefaces

In PrimeFaces 10, how can we get the `filterValue` list from a `dataTable` using `LazyModel`? The example below uses `getFilterBy()`, which always returns `null`. How can we fix it, please?

```java
public List<DataDto> load(int first,
                          int pageSize,
                          Map<String, SortMeta> multiSortMeta,
                          Map<String, FilterMeta> filters) {
  if (filters.isEmpty()) {
    filters = table.getFilterByAsMap();
  }
  if (!filters.isEmpty()) {
    for (FilterMeta entry : filters.values()) {

      String filterProperty = entry.getField();
      FilterConstraint constF = entry.getConstraint();
      Object filterValue = entry.getFilterBy();

      if (filterProperty.equals("customer")) {
        List<Object> selectedCustomers = Arrays.asList(filterValue);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```java
Object filterValue = entry.getFilterValue();
```

A full example of lazy filtering can be found here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Have a look at the `LazyCustomerDataModel.java` class:

```java
public class LazyCustomerDataModel extends LazyDataModel<Customer> {

    private List<Customer> datasource;

    public LazyCustomerDataModel(List<Customer> datasource) {
        this.datasource = datasource;
    }

    @Override
    public Customer getRowData(String rowKey) {
        for (Customer customer : datasource) {
            if (customer.getId() == Integer.parseInt(rowKey)) {
                return customer;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getRowKey(Customer customer) {
        return String.valueOf(customer.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> load(int offset, int pageSize, Map<String, SortMeta> sortBy, Map<String, FilterMeta> filterBy) {
        long rowCount = datasource.stream()
                .filter(o -> filter(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), filterBy.values(), o))
                .count();

        // apply offset & filters
        List<Customer> customers = datasource.stream()
                .skip(offset)
                .filter(o -> filter(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), filterBy.values(), o))
                .limit(pageSize)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        // sort
        if (!sortBy.isEmpty()) {
            List<Comparator<Customer>> comparators = sortBy.values().stream()
                    .map(o -> new LazySorter(o.getField(), o.getOrder()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            Comparator<Customer> cp = ComparatorUtils.chainedComparator(comparators); // from apache
            customers.sort(cp);
        }

        // rowCount
        setRowCount((int) rowCount);

        return customers;
    }


    private boolean filter(FacesContext context, Collection<FilterMeta> filterBy, Object o) {
        boolean matching = true;

        for (FilterMeta filter : filterBy) {
            FilterConstraint constraint = filter.getConstraint();
            Object filterValue = filter.getFilterValue();

            try {
                Object columnValue = String.valueOf(o.getClass().getField(filter.getField()).get(o));
                matching = constraint.isMatching(context, columnValue, filterValue, LocaleUtils.getCurrentLocale());
            } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
                matching = false;
            }

            if (!matching) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return matching;
    }
}
```